# How to get variable from a class to another Tkinter window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

The goal is to pass the variable **string1** from `class Display` to be used in another Tkinter window.
So when the button named **Next** [in `class Display` load function] is clicked, it would open a new Tkinter window. And in the new window, the variable **string1** from `class Display` needs to be retrieved for further action. May i know should i create another class Display2, or should i just add a method in the class Display?

Currently the string variable can be passed as reference from `class Display` to the `class Action_Data`. But how can it be passed to another Tkinter window when the button **Next** is clicked?
I am trying to get the variable via the callback function new_window. Just not sure if it's how it's done. Any pointer would be appreciated. Many thanks.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

#Application window
root = tk.Tk()

#Display Class
class Display (tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, display_data):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.master = master
        
        #passing data as reference
        self.display= display_data
        #button
        self.load_button = tk.Button(self, text="Load", command=self.load)
        self.load_button.pack()
        
    def new_window(self):
        
        self.master = tk.Tk() # create another Tk instance       
        var_string2 = Label(self, text="<<string1 value>>") 
        var_string2.pack()     
        print (var_string2)
               
    def load(self):
     
        #get value
        string1='value1'
        self.display.action1(string1)
    
        self.acition_button = tk.Button(self, text="Next", 
        command=self.new_window)
        self.acition_button.pack()
    
    
#Action_Data Class         
class Action_Data(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
               
    def action1(self, path1):
       
        var_path1 = path1
        print(var_path1)
        
display= Action_Data(root)
display.pack()

reader = Display(root, display)
reader.pack()

pathlabel2 = Label(root)
root.mainloop()
```

*`Issue`*

Now the new window is blank and cannot retrieve the value of variable string1 from the load function

[image]

Error

[image]

Comment: Please try to combine this code into a single [mcve].

Comment: @BryanOakley code updated, please take a look, many thanks

Comment: Why do you want to destroy the window and create another one? Why don't you just remove the items in your current window and put new items in? That way you can just keep the things around that you want to keep, like the StringVar.

Comment: @JacksonPro code edited, the expected output is for the new window to be able to get the  value of variable string1 from load method

Comment: @Novel, content replacement is a good suggestion, could you shed some light on how this could be done, many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `lambda` function to pass the button's `command`, that way you can pass the needed string as an argument.

You do not need to create two instances of `Tk`, if you need another window, create a `Toplevel`.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

#Application window
root = tk.Tk()

#Display Class
class Display (tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, display_data):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.master = master
        

        #passing data as reference
        self.display= display_data
        #button
        self.load_button = tk.Button(self, text="Load", command=self.load)
        self.load_button.pack()
    
    def new_window(self, string):
        #self.master.destroy() # close the current window
        new_window  = tk.Toplevel() # create toplevel       
        var_string2 = Label(new_window, text=string)  
        var_string2.pack()
        new_window.focus() 
        print (var_string2.cget("text"))
           
    def load(self):
 
        #get value
        string1='value1'
        self.display.action1(string1)

        self.acition_button = tk.Button(self, text="Next", 
        command= lambda : self.new_window(string1))
        self.acition_button.pack()



#Action_Data Class         
class Action_Data(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
           
    def action1(self, path1):
   
        var_path1 = path1
        print(var_path1)
            
display= Action_Data(root)
display.pack()

reader = Display(root, display)
reader.pack()

pathlabel2 = Label(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: may i ask if there's multiple strings, can i use "+" to concat all the strings, so that all strings can be passed to the new window? thankyou

Comment: If you will use them as one string, then concatenate them, if you will use them separately, pass all of them as individual arguments, there is no real limit to the number of arguments you can pass.